# .Net 7.0 how to fix https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"

Tags: c#, .net, http-status-code-415

When i trying to sign in or sign Up at my web app i receive this problem .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7aiz.png)
IAuthService:

```
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Models.Auth;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Models.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAuthService
    {
        Task<User> RegisterAsync(UserRequestDto request);
        Task<User> LoginAsync(UserRequestLogDto request);
        Task<User> LoggoutAsync(UserRequestLogDto request);

    }
}
```

AuthService:

```
using Azure.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Core.Interfaces;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Models.Auth;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Models.Models;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Web.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Core.Services
{
    public class AuthService : IAuthService
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

        public AuthService(DataContext context, IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _context = context;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        public async Task<User> RegisterAsync(UserRequestDto request)
        {
            if (await _context.Users.AnyAsync(u => u.Email == request.Email))
            {
                return null; 
            }

            string passwordHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(request.Password);

            var user = new User
            {
                UserName = request.Username,
                Email = request.Email,
                PasswordHash = passwordHash
            };

            var welcomeEmail = new EmailModel
            {
                Email = request.Email,
                Subject = "Mail for successfully registration at GnomeLove",
                Message = $"Welcome {user.UserName} to Dating Web APP GnomeLove, good luck in searching your love ^_^"
            };
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(welcomeEmail.Email, welcomeEmail.Subject, welcomeEmail.Message);

            _context.Users.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return user; 
        }

        public async Task<User> LoginAsync(UserRequestLogDto request)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == request.Email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (!BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(request.Password, user.PasswordHash))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return user;
        }

        public async Task<User> LoggoutAsync(UserRequestLogDto request)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == request.Email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

AuthController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Core.Interfaces;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Models.Auth;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Models.Models;
using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Core.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Data;

namespace Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthService _authService;

        public AuthController(IAuthService authService)
        {
            _authService = authService;
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Register(UserRequestDto request)
        {
            var user = await _authService.RegisterAsync(request);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Email is already registered.");
            }

            return Ok(user);
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Login(UserRequestLogDto request)
        {
            var user = await _authService.LoginAsync(request);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid email or password.");
            }

            return Ok(user);
        }

        [HttpPost("logout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(UserRequestLogDto request)
        {
            var result = await _authService.LoggoutAsync(request);

            if (result != null)
            {
                return Ok("Logout successful.");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Logout failed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

_LoginPartial:

```
@using Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Models.Models;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@inject SignInManager<User> signInManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                @User.Identity!.Name!
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="loggout">
                        Logout
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
    else{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="login">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-16" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Web.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/svg" href="/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">GnomeLove</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/swagger">Swagger UI</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2024 - Mykhailo Ryzhanovskyi - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

User:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ryzhanovskyi.University.Tinder.Models.Models
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public override string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        public override string PasswordHash { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email adress.")]
        public override string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int Age { get; set; } = 18;
        public string Gender { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string City { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string Photo {  get; set; } = string.Empty;

    }

}
```

I was trying to change utf-8 to utf-16 but it doesnt work, and watches video or i`m stupid or can`t understand this.

i expecting to fix this problem, Thanks!

Comment: 415 unsupported error indicates that the request is sending the wrong data type likely. Has this been verified? Is it sending in XML or text instead of `application/json`?

Comment: Login API is a ``POST`` but when you're calling it from the browser it's calling the API via ``GET``, try to use Postman or other tools to use Post HTTP method

Comment: Postman is more robust than the Net library for making http connection.  Postman will automatically add addition http headers to get connection to work while c# does not add http headers without you adding the headers to your code.  So when Postman works use the Control Panel in Postman to get the actual http request that was sent and check the http headers.  Then add the missing (or modified) headers to you c# code